# C# powershell remote authorization prompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

I am making an application that sends your powershell script to the computer you want and run it, as directed on this:

[image: my powershell app]

here is my script for c#:

```
textBox1.Text = RunScript("Invoke-Command -ComputerName"+ ComputerName +" -ScriptBlock {"+ textBox2.Text +"} -credential"+ textBox5.Text);
```

i also tried it in powershell with everything filled in and it works but it asks for a authorization like this:

[image: authorization prompt]

I want to basiclly bypass this and connect to the computer with no prompts or manually done like
-credentials Username but also for password.

or when this happens open a prompt for this ontop of this form. Here is full script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PowershellOpen
{
    public partial class Florm1 : Form
    {
        public bool gg = false;
        public string ComputerName;
        public string CustomScript;
        public string password;
        public string user;

        public Florm1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private string RunScript(string scriptText)
        {
            // create Powershell runspace 
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

            // open it 
            runspace.Open();

            // create a pipeline and feed it the script text 
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

            pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

            // execute the script 
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

            // close the runspace 
            runspace.Close();

            // convert the script result into a single string 
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }

            // return the results of the script that has 
            // now been converted to text 
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
        // helper method that takes your script path, loads up the script 
        // into a variable, and passes the variable to the RunScript method 
        // that will then execute the contents 
        private string LoadScript(string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from our file. 
                // The using statement also closes the StreamReader. 
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
                {

                    // use a string builder to get all our lines from the file 
                    StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder();

                    // string to hold the current line 
                    string curLine;

                    // loop through our file and read each line into our 
                    // stringbuilder as we go along 
                    while ((curLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // read each line and MAKE SURE YOU ADD BACK THE 
                        // LINEFEED THAT IT THE ReadLine() METHOD STRIPS OFF 
                        fileContents.Append(curLine + "\n");
                    }


                    return fileContents.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string errorText = "The file could not be read:";
                errorText += e.Message + "\n";
                return errorText;
            }

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            textBox1.Text = RunScript("Invoke-Command -ComputerName"+ ComputerName +" -ScriptBlock {"+ textBox2.Text +"} -credential"+ textBox5.Text);
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox3.Text = ComputerName;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Succesfully Cleared";
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "HELP: The way this launcher works is it launches the powershell scripts,(you can find these in the folder this comes with) this makes using powershell alot easier and accesible. This is a easy place to find all your scripts.";
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.LightSeaGreen;
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = RunScript(LoadScript(@textBox3.Text));
                textBox1.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;


        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = RunScript("Test-WsMan "+textBox3.Text);
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prompting for credentials is the default behavior of the `-Credential` when supplied with just a username.

You can supply a credential object without prompting for credentials with `ConvertTo-SecureString` and `New-Object`:

```
$Username = 'squeek'
$Password = 'p4swrd' |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$Credential = New-Object pscredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password
```

In your compacted single-line example, that would look like:

```
"Invoke-Command -ComputerName"+ ComputerName +" -ScriptBlock {"+ textBox2.Text +"} -credential $(New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList '" + usernameTextBox.Text + "',$('" + passwordTextBox.Text + "' |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force))";
```

Comment: UR A LEGEND Thanks soooo much

Comment: @Squeek Separate the statements with `;`, or use the example I gave with nested subexpressions (`$()`), or use a verbatim string literal (`@""`) in the C# code (which support multiple lines). If the answer solves your problem, please "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left

Comment: i tried this but it came up with this The term 'p4swrd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add proper quotation marks inside the string. Also 'squeekpro' is a terrible password

Comment: this is the new error  Cannot find type [pscredential]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded

Comment: this is the new error  Cannot find type [pscredential]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded @Mathias R. Jessen

Comment: @Squeek Is this PowerShell 2.0? Use the full type name: `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential`

Comment: how would i put this in and where @Mathias R. Jessen

Comment: It says system error when i added it in @Mathias R. Jessen